# Display different text based on iPad orientation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm wanting to display different text on an iPad only when in portrait mode.

Using data attributes, I can store the portrait text, but how can I detect the orientation change and apply the text on the iPad?

My markup currently looks like this;

```
<h2 class="searchLink" data-landscape="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam" data-portrait="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam</h2>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever heard of `media queries?` You don't need jQuery, you can use `CSS`.

Look at [this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) tutorial for example:

Comment: Already using media queries.. So your suggesting show/hide (h2 in this case) based on device width then?

Comment: Yes, of course. For example, you can set `display: none` in your media query for the element you don't want to show on your Ipad.

Comment: I'd like to keep the DOM clean of additional markup, so I don't think hiding with a media query is quite right here..

Comment: Well, that depends on your preferences of course. I would have preferred my way, but I respect your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the [orientationChange event](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html). So if you were using jQuery/zepto.js (other DOM libraries are available etc) you can do

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function() {
    //call your text swapping fn here
  });
```

Mobile Safari also exposes `window.orientation` which returns an integer representing the current orientation (possible values being 0,90,180,-90). You can then check that in your fn to decide which text to show.

You'll probably need to wrap all this in a `if(window.orientation)` conditional to avoid errors in non-supporting browsers.